# Canonically, what languages has C-3P0 been shown to know?

Tags: star-wars, languages, c-3po

We all know that C-3P0 is

> fluent in over six million forms of communication

Over the films we see him speak and/or understand Basic, Huttese, Shyriiwook, rudimentary Ewokese and other languages.

Throughout the canon universe, what "forms of communication" is he shown to be able to use?

Comment: Also certainly he speaks Droid, or whatever R2D2 speaks.  Although, from his rudely interrupting Han and Leia in The Force Awakens, we can assume that he lacks tact and can't read body language - but then, he was built by a child psychopath out of scrap in a desert!

Comment: He uses half a dozen new languages in every single novel he appears in. I'd guess the answer will run into the hundreds of examples.

Comment: Botchi language

Answer (score 5):

Basic, Binary, Bocce, Ewokese (Ewok), Huttese, Shyriiwook (Wookiee), [Ubese](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ubese_(language)) (bounty hunter Leia), and whatever that other protocol droid speaks in *Empire*.

You'll have to resort to the EU to find the five million, nine hundred ninety-nine thousand, nine hundred ninety-two other ones.

Comment: Didnt he react to an alien speaking some other language in Jabba the huts palace? I could be misremembering.

Comment: @john - No, he just wasn't sure what he said in Huttese. But you reminded me of the bounty hunter, Boushh.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see, we know he speaks Bocce, the language of Binary Load Lifters, very similar to moisture vaporators, and can converse with R2.  He has had conversations with Chewbacca, and was able to discern the language of the Ewoks.